# Which class should I import to use verifyTrue

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using Selenium with TestNG using dataProvider. I am verifying the list which have hundred names. I have added all of these into an excel sheet with comma separated in A CELL. I have programmed in Java as below:

```
import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.*;
public class example extends Base{
    @Test(dataProvider="List")
    public void isListofNamesPresent(String names) throws Exception
    String list[] = names.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent(list[i]));
        Reporter.log("Type of Case:"+ names +" are present");
    }
}
```

The above code asserts the list of names which are put in A CELL as (Aaron, James, Jack, Hegin, Henry).Since it has only one round of data it exits the method if any error between actual and expected because of assertTrue. If i give verifyTrue then it should get execute all the list even though there is a mismatch between actual and expected.

Can anyone please tell me how to use verifyTrue? I mean which class i need to import. I cannot extend any class as I have already extended a Base Class. So any import will do. I tried with SeleneseTestCase but no luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it would be to create your own `verifyTrue()` method that does something like this to catch the assert error:

```
public static void verifyTrue(boolean condition, String message) {
    try {
        Assert.assertTrue(condition, message);
        log("Expected value: true" + " Actual value: " + condition + " - PASSED ", true);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log("Expected value: true" + " Actual value: " + condition + " - FAILED " + message, true);
        addVerificationFailure(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code shows the use of assertTrue implicitly. As I have understand, the poster wants to use verifyTrue instead of assertTrue. So, it needs some code to use only verifyTrue excluding assertTrue

Comment: Because the method above catches the assert's exception, it solves the poster's problem of assertTrue exiting the method -- verifyTrue here will not cause an escape.

Answer (score 0):

You can import SeleneseTestBase class to use verifyTrue() as below:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
```

SeleneseTestCase can also be used, but it is deprecated. So. it is better to use SeleneseTestBase